# Tool Tips not working in Java

Tags: java, tooltip

SOLVED
I am trying to follow the tutorial here : http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/, but when I get to the part about tooltips it will not work. 
the code I have is

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TooltipExample extends JFrame {

    public TooltipExample() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setToolTipText("A Panel container");

        JButton btn = new JButton("Button");
        btn.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        btn.setToolTipText("A Button component");

        panel.add(btn);

        setTitle("Tooltip");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TooltipExample ex = new TooltipExample();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

, but when I hover over a button so tooltip shows... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure ? Try to stay few seconds hover the button without moving.

Comment: wow what a stupid mistake... that solved it.

Comment: *"what am I doing wrong?"* - `panel.setLayout(null);`.  Modern UI's are expected to operate within a diverse range of operating systems and environments, all of which have their own ideas of how a font should be rendered.  Layout managers take the guess work out of this problem.

Comment: yes, but the purpose of this was not to create something releasable, but rather a very simple tutorial for a java noob(myself).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the solution was to just mouse over the button a bit longer and wait for the tool tip.  Sometimes when you are running a program locally it takes a second for the cpu to catch up.  I was going to mention how to change the natural tool tip delay with this swing manager in case it helps the next person. 
[Oracle Docs for ToolTipManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html)